# Araxis merge three-way file comparison with Git

Tags: git, araxis-merge

Below is the setting in my .gitconfig, but i only see 2 panes in Araxis Merge when I merge. What's the configuration to activate 3-way merge?

```
[mergetool "araxis"]
    path = C:\\Programs\\Tools\\Araxis\\Araxis Merge\\compare.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably not using the "**Professional Edition**".
Three-way comparison and merging is enabled within Professional Edition only.

refer to:

- https://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-windows/three-way-file-comparison-and-merging.en

  > The **Professional Edition** of Merge enables you to compare and merge **three files** side-by-side.
- https://www.araxis.com/merge/features.en